# URL Rewrite keeps returning 404 Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've created a .htaccess file for the URL rewrite, and I tested it using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it says the URL rewrite is correct, but when testing the page keeps giving me a 404 error.

Here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ /article/index.php?id=$1
```

The URL rewrite I need is the following:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/article/test  // To redirect to: 
http://www.mydomain.com/article/index.php?k=test
```

Can anyone tell me what I am messing up?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure a file exists named `/article/index.php` and then give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Condition: the requested file is non-existent
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ /article/index.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you so much! Just for the record, can you explain to me what was wrong? (The file did exist when I was getting the error.)

Comment: Ok, my client's server is returning a 404 now, but the rewrite works. What should I change if I have to do the following rewrite:

` http://www.mydomain.com/articles/article/test `
` http://www.mydomain.com/articles/article/index.php?k=test `

Sorry for the dumb questions, but I haven't used .htaccess files before and I don't know how to debug.